# CSRF-токен в куках

Tags: php, алгоритм, cookie, защита, csrf

почему некоторые сайты хранят `CSRF-токен` в куках?

Ведь если отправить, к примеру, `GET-запрос` - `<img src="http://bank.com?act=make"` или `POST`, то на сервер отправятся и куки, и проверка будет пройдена.

или я что-то не понимаю??

Comment: Ну... да. А это точно CSRF-токен? Не идентификатор сессии?

Comment: @D-side да, точно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Само по себе это действительно бесполезно, если сервер помнит соответствие *токен-пользователь* и проверяет только его.

Но в сочетании с передачей **такого же** токена в параметрах это становится быстрым и простым способом защиты от CSRF: вы ставите пользователю в куки **совершенно случайный токен** и проверяете, что в параметрах запроса впоследствии приходит **точно такой же**. Проверяется соответствие *запрос-кука*.

Потенциальный атакующий не сможет достать его из-за **Same Origin Policy** (можно ещё досыпать сверху `HttpOnly`, чтобы не получить дыр из-за JS), а потому не сможет его продублировать в запросе. И нет необходимости запоминать что-либо на сервере.